# Row with latest value by customer and month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that keeps track of changes in customer profiles. [Here's a simplified version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e493a/1):

```
CREATE TABLE HISTORY (
    CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER(9,0), 
    DATE_CHANGED DATE, 
    ACCOUNT_TYPE VARCHAR2(20),

    CONSTRAINT HISTORY_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED)
);

INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (200, TO_DATE('05/01/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Premium');
INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (300, TO_DATE('17/02/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Free');
INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (100, TO_DATE('05/03/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Free');
INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (100, TO_DATE('12/03/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Standard');
INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (200, TO_DATE('22/03/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Standard');
INSERT INTO HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED, ACCOUNT_TYPE) VALUES (100, TO_DATE('29/03/2013 00:00:00','DD/MM/RRRR HH24:MI:SS'), 'Premium');
```

That data is maintained by a third-party. My ultimate goal is to obtain a sum of customers per account type and month for a given timespan but, by now, I'd like to start with something simpler—display the latest account type for each month/customer combination where there are changes recorded:

```
YEAR MONTH CUSTOMER_ID ACCOUNT_TYPE
==== ===== =========== ============
2013     1         200 Premium
2013     2         300 Free
2013     3         100 Premium
2013     3         200 Standard
```

Here, customer 100 has made three changes on March; we display "Premium" because it has the latest date within March.

The query to obtain *all* rows would be this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS YEAR,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS MONTH,
CUSTOMER_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE
FROM HISTORY
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, DATE_CHANGED
```

Is it possible to filter out unwanted rows using aggregate functions? Does it make more sense to use analytic functions?

(And, in either case, what would be the adequate function?)

**Edit:** I've been asked for an example of unwanted rows. There're 3 rows for customer 100 on March:

```
'05/03/2013 00:00:00', 'Free'
'12/03/2013 00:00:00', 'Standard'
'29/03/2013 00:00:00', 'Premium'
```

Unwanted rows are `'Free'` and `'Standard'` because they aren't the latest in the month.

Comment: Can you give an example of "unwanted rows"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT YEAR
      ,MONTH
      ,customer_id
      ,max(ACCOUNT_TYPE) keep(dense_rank FIRST ORDER BY date_changed DESC) LAST_ACC
 FROM (
  SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS YEAR,
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS MONTH,
         CUSTOMER_ID,
         date_changed,
         account_type
   FROM HISTORY
  )
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, customer_id
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID


| YEAR | MONTH | CUSTOMER_ID | LAST_ACC |
-----------------------------------------
| 2013 |     1 |         200 |  Premium |
| 2013 |     2 |         300 |     Free |
| 2013 |     3 |         100 |  Premium |
| 2013 |     3 |         200 | Standard |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e493a/15

Comment: Looks great. If I understand your code, `max(ACCOUNT_TYPE)` fetches `ACCOUNT_TYPE` where `DATE_CHANGED` is greatest (not the maximum value of `ACCOUNT_TYPE` per-se). Am I correct?

Comment: yeah, it takes maximum value only for rows which have maximum date_changed in current year/month/customer group, the remaining rows are ignored.

Comment: And since we have only one maximum date per group (as per the PK), i.e., only one row per group, we could also use `MIN()` and get the same result. Thank you, I had something like this in mind but couldn't get the pieces together.

Comment: you can also add more sorting fields to `dense rank first/last order by` to ensure uniqueness

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
CUSTOMER_ID,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS YEAR,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS MONTH,
LAST_VALUE(ACCOUNT_TYPE) 
OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID,TO_CHAR(DATE_CHANGED,'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY DATE_CHANGED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS ACCOUNT_TYPE
FROM HISTORY



CUSTOMER_ID YEAR    MONTH   ACCOUNT_TYPE
200         2013    1   Premium
300         2013    2   Free
100         2013    3   Premium
200         2013    3   Standard
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fab60/13

Comment: `LAST_VALUE()` has the exact semantic of what I want to do, «return the last value in an ordered set of values», and I love that. It's a pity that it doesn't remove rows by itself :)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Yes,it can't remove rows by itself,but maybe in other situations this feature would be useful. : )   .

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YEAR, MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE
FROM 
(
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS YEAR,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED) AS MONTH,
       CUSTOMER_ID, 
       ACCOUNT_TYPE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, 
                                       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED),
                                       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED)
                          ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_CHANGED) DESC,
                                   EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_CHANGED) DESC,
                                   DATE_CHANGED DESC) RN
FROM   HISTORY
)
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH, CUSTOMER_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e493a/17)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═══════╦═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ YEAR ║ MONTH ║ CUSTOMER_ID ║ ACCOUNT_TYPE ║
╠══════╬═══════╬═════════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2013 ║     1 ║         200 ║ Premium      ║
║ 2013 ║     2 ║         300 ║ Free         ║
║ 2013 ║     3 ║         100 ║ Premium      ║
║ 2013 ║     3 ║         200 ║ Standard     ║
╚══════╩═══════╩═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: If I understand the code, `PARTITION BY` defines a row subset where `DATE_CHANGED` is unique (as per the PK). Then, it'd be enough to do `ORDER BY DATE_CHANGED DESC` in the `OVER` clause, wouldn't it?